# The integral of the $x-$th root of a

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it possible to find integral of the $x-$th root of $a$ (written as $\int(a^{1/x}dx)$)?  From what I've found searching around on the internet, there is almost no discussion of it, let alone a solution.

I have found that $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{-a^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\ln\left(a\right)})$ is $\frac{a^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}$, but that is still a fairly substantial distance from my question.

Answer (score 1):

Maple does it in terms of the (non-elementary) exponential integral function:

$$
\int a^{1/x}\;dx = 
\log(a)\operatorname{Ei}_1\left(\frac{-\log(a)}{x}\right)
+x a^{1/x} .
$$

The exponential integral function $\operatorname{Ei}_1$is known to be not elementary.  It can be
defined (up to a constant) by

$$
\frac{d}{dz}\operatorname{Ei}_1(z) = -\frac{e^{-z}}{z} .
$$